# React Native app won't update states until I leave app and then go back to it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, notifications

In my react native app, I have it so users can set local notifications for a specific event (by tapping on a button). However users might toggle off/on notifications in the iOS settings and when the user does that and goes back to the app, the state didn't take affect. The only way it does go into affect is when the user goes out of the app and then goes back in.

```
export default class Bell extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      isNotifActive: true,
      isBellActive: false,
      alertBody:"",
      fireDate: "",
      LaunchStatus: "",
      notificationPermission: ""

    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        alertBody: this.props.alertBody,
        fireDate:this.props.fireDate,
        LaunchStatus: this.props.LaunchStatus
    }) 
    AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
      if (state === 'active') {
        Permissions.check('notification').then(response => { // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
          this.setState({ notificationPermission: response })
        })
        if(this.state.notificationPermission == 'authorized') this.setState({isNotifActive:true}) //problem
        else if(this.state.notificationPermission != 'authorized') this.setState({isNotifActive:false})

      }
      if (state === 'background') {
        Permissions.check('notification').then(response => { // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
          this.setState({ notificationPermission: response })
        })
        if(this.state.notificationPermission == 'authorized') this.setState({isNotifActive:true}) //problem?
        else if(this.state.notificationPermission != 'authorized') this.setState({isNotifActive:false}) 
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    let LaunchStatus = this.state.LaunchStatus
    return (

      <Ionicons
        name={this.state.isBellActive? "md-notifications":"md-notifications-off"}
        color={"white"}
        size={30}
        style={styles.NotifIcon}
        onPress={() => {
            Vibration.vibrate()
            if(this.state.isNotifActive == true){
              if(LaunchStatus == 2){
                Alert.alert(
                  'No Notification Made',
                  'No launch time is available at the moment, you may toggle a notification when a launch time is made.',
                  [
                    {text: 'OK'},
                  ]
                );
              }
              else{
                if(this.state.isBellActive){
                  PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
                      alertTitle: "Launching Soon:",
                      alertBody: this.state.alertBody,
                      fireDate: this.state.fireDate // in 30 mins
                  });
                  this.setState({NotifIcon : "md-notifications"});
                  this.setState({isBellActive : false});
                  }
                  else if(this.state.isBellActive != true){
                      PushNotificationIOS.cancelLocalNotifications();
                      this.setState({NotifIcon : "md-notifications-off"}); 
                      this.setState({isBellActive : true});
                  }
                }
            }
            else if(this.state.isNotifActive == false){
              PushNotificationIOS.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
              this.setState({NotifIcon : "md-notifications-off"});
              }
            }}
        />
    );
  }  
}
```

What the code does above is check whether the app is active or in the background and then it checks the state of the notification permission on iOS. If notifications are not toggled the user shouldn't be able to toggle a notification in the app and vice versa. It works, however only after the user toggles off/on notification -> goes into the app -> goes out of the app -> then goes back in to the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I took away the eventListener in the componentDidMount and instead installed firebase only to add:

```
  firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
    .then(enabled => {
      if (enabled) {
        this.setState({isNotifActive: true})
      } else {
        this.setState({isNotifActive: false})
    } 
    });
```

in the render after the "Let Launches......" statement.